# Visual Studio Code: How to configure includePath for better IntelliSense results

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am a complete beginner to using Visual Studio Code and I have no clue what I am doing.

I've searched around (maybe not enough), but I can't find just a simple explanation for someone like me on how to configure the `c_cpp_properties.json` file that I am redirected to whenever I click on the yellow light bulb next to a line that is underlined with a green squiggle.

[Lightbulb example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gxQw.png)

[c_cpp_properties.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMlGq.png)

I just want to know what to put in the `.json` to make IntelliSense work properly.

Answer (score 36):

> From the official documentation of the C/C++ extension:

### Configuring includePath for better IntelliSense results

If you're seeing the following message when opening a folder in Visual Studio Code, it means the C++ IntelliSense engine needs additional information about the paths in which your include files are located.

[image: Configure includePath for better IntelliSense]

#### Where are the include paths defined?

The include paths are defined in the `"includePath"` setting in a file called **c_cpp_properties.json** located in the .vscode directory in the opened folder.

You can create or open this file by either using the `"C/Cpp: Edit Configurations"` command in the command palette or by selecting `"Edit "includePath" setting"` in the light bulb menu (see the screenshot below). The quickest way to locate a light bulb is to scroll to the top of the source file and click on any green squiggle that shows up under a #include statement.

[image: lightbulb menu "Edit "includePath" setting"]

When a folder is opened, the extension attempts to locate your system headers based on your operating system, but it does not know about any other libraries that your project depends on. You can hover over the green squiggles or open the Problems window to understand which headers the IntelliSense engine is unable to open - sometimes it's the dependent headers that can't be located.

[image: include error message]

#### How can I specify the include paths?

You can specify the remaining paths using one of the techniques described below.

1. Use compile_commands.json file to supply includePaths and defines information

   The extension can get the information for `"includePath"` and `"defines"` from a compile_commands.json file, which can be auto-generated by many build systems such as CMake and Ninja. Look for the section where your current configuration is defined (by default there's one configuration per operating system, such as "Win32 or "Mac"), and set the `"compileCommands"` property in **c_cpp_properties.json** to the full path to your compile_commands.json file and the extension will use that instead of the `"includes"` and `"defines"` properties for IntelliSense.

   [image: use compileCommands setting]
2. Use the light bulb suggestions to auto-resolve includePath

   The first thing to try is to leverage the light bulb path suggestions to auto-resolve the include paths. When you open a folder, the extension will **recursively** search for potential include paths that match the header files your code is using based on the paths set by the `"browse.path"` setting in **c_cpp_properties.json**. Click on the green squiggles under #include statements and you'll see a light bulb offering suggestions of paths that will allow IntelliSense to resolve the included file.

   [image: lightbulb suggestions]

   If you don't see path suggestions in the light bulb, try adding the root folder where the headers are likely located in to the `"browse.path"` setting in **c_cpp_properties.json**. This allows the extension to **recursively** search in these folders and offer more suggestions in the light bulb as the search process goes on.
3. Manually add include paths

   If none of the above fully resolves the paths, you could manually specify the paths to the headers that your project depends on in the **c_cpp_properties.json** file. Look for the section where your current configuration is defined (by default there's one configuration per OS, such as "Win32 or "Mac"), and add your paths in the `"includePath"` setting and defines in the `"defines"` setting. For example, the following screenshot shows a snippet of the file specifying path for the Mac configuration.

   Also, for MinGW, [as the documentation of the extension explains](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/MinGW.md) you may ask *gcc/g++* to list its own include files:

   ```
   gcc -v -E -x c++ nul
   ```

   [image: c_cpp_properties file snippet]

#### Verify the include paths are correctly resolved

There are two ways to verify that the include paths are correctly resolved:

1. The green squiggles in the source file are no longer showing
2. Error messages are cleared in the Problems window

This indicates that the IntelliSense engine has got the include paths resolved so you can start enjoying the full IntelliSense for your C or C++ code for the current translation unit. Note that you may still see errors on other files if they belong to a different translation unit that requires additional include paths to be configured.

#### If this didn't resolve your issue then, check out the configuration for MinGW below and try setting the appropriate location for your Cygwin installation for the respective/similar header files & folders.

*[Configuring MinGW](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/MinGW.md)*

*[c_cpp_properties.json reference guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md)*

Comment: you simply copy/pasted official doc, didn't you?

Comment: Didn't you see the first text of my answer ?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. But do you really think acknowledging the source is enough? that there's nothing wrong with this kind of copy/pasting?

Comment: I myself have been contributing to the development of this C/C++ extension for VSCode, therefore, I think I deserve this right to at least copy, edit and post a part of documentation for someone who might be in need of it and doesn't have a clue about it. Plus, I've also linked the original sources in the end.

Comment: @ShihabShahriar Strictly speaking the source repo is under the MIT licence, so the documentation probably is too, which by extension might mean this answer is also under the MIT licence.

Comment: All your image URLs are broken

Comment: Replace `https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/raw/ronglu-edit/Images/` to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/03c6c4df1d1c39a8b2a5522a8df96effeb3c2196/Images/` in all your image links. Always point to a specific commit.

Answer (score 5):

From *[C/C++ for Visual Studio Code (Preview)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)*:

> Below you can see that the MinGW C++ include path has been added to browse.path for Windows:

```
{
"name": "Win32",
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceRoot}"
],
"defines": [
    "_DEBUG",
    "UNICODE"
],
"intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
"browse": {
    "path": [
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
    ],
    "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
    "databaseFilename": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I have cygwin installed, do you know what the code would be for that?

Comment: Also when I put in any code that is different from the original code it gives an error "Failed to parse "e:\\.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json": Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1896"

Answer (score 0):

VSCode is very adept at asking the *compiler* what include paths it is using if you set things up correctly.  Part of my project uses a DSP compiler based on GCC, so by adding "-v" to the compiler's flags (I put it in CFLAGS in my Makefile) I was able to see the internal command lines which revealed the "secret" flags being passed to the lower compiler levels.  This showed me what "-D" values I needed to add to the "defines" section of my config and, more importantly, that "-isystem" was being used to set the system include directory.  I ended up with this in my c_cpp_properties.json:-

```
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "CEVA-V15",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "CEVAXC323",
            "XC323_CEVA"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/devtools/CEVA-ToolBox/V15/CEVA-XC/cevaxccc",
        "cStandard": "gnu11",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-arm",
        "compilerArgs": [
            "-isystem /devtools/CEVA-ToolBox/V15/CEVA-XC/include"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, Visual Studio Code's C/C++ extension has an UI for IntelliSense configuration. No need to edit the configuration in bare json.

You can open IntelliSense configuration UI through command palette: Type Ctrl + Shift + P  and search for "Edit configurations".

[image: command palette]

I'd like to explain the configuration of an include path by way of example:

I have a project using an old cross compiler. The include files reside in `C:\Program Files\Keil\C51\INC`

IntelliSense knows nothing about the compilers include files. Thus I see include paths with red squiggly lines. When I click on the line I see the yellow light bulb. I click on the light bulb and a list of suggestions opens.

[image: source code with red error squiggles]

Clicking on `Edit "compilerPath" setting` opens IntelliSense configuration pane.

Scroll to "Include path" and add the include path in the text field.

[image: configuration pane]

Now the red squiggles are gone.

[image: source code]