# Including a full file path on VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include

I am trying to run a code example which has an include displayed this way

```
#include "..\..\..\library\inc\CyUSBSerial.h"
```

Of course this does not build because VS Code cannot find this file. so I tried copy pasting the full path like this

```
#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\CYUSBS234 DVK\1.0\library\lib\CyUSBSerial.h"
```

but I get red squiggles when doing so. I believe this is because it is not the right way to write full paths? But I can't find this information online.

How can I include this file in my project, which isn't in the same directory at all?

Thank you!

Comment: VS Code should somehow know where to look for includes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258143/visual-studio-code-how-to-configure-includepath-for-better-intellisense-results) may be helpful.

Comment: Use forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing all the "\" with "/"

```
#include "../../../library/inc/CyUSBSerial.h"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is still complaining. Am I supposed to add an includepath somewhere, too? How can windows know what ../../../ means and where to find the specified file? Thank you!

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheS-Brisson, yes, you should specify includepath.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheS-Brisson the "../" takes you a directory back from where you write it in