# How to Setup &Configure MongoDB C/C++ (11/17)drivers in Visual Studio Code on Windows-10

Tags: c++, windows, mongodb, visual-studio-code

Has anyone successfully installed C++(11/17) MongoDB drivers for developing CRUD applications/operations on Visual Studio Code on Windows10? Can you please send me a sample/instructions. I have downloaded MongoDB C and C++ drivers and built them but not able to move forward configuring them in VS Code to write CRUD operations.

**I need help in setting and configuring these drivers to work in VS-Code.**

Comment: In linux I had to update my includePath to make intellisense work with the C++ driver in VSCode. I imagine it might be the same on Windows. This post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48015407/2028838