# How do I get VSCode to recognise my GTK installation?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gtk3

I am trying to install GTK on Windows 10 via MINGW64 and getting it to work with my VSCode C script.

I have followed the steps listed within [this link](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/) as well as checking the installation. While MINGW64 is confirming that the install is successful, VS Code highlights `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` as an error, stating that it cannot find the header file.

Comment: did you https://stackoverflow.com/q/46258143/11107541 ?